# FUNCTIONS : Theoretical doubt on functions 2

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

In the functional mathematics language , if i represent function by $$f$$ .

What is the theoretical difference between$$f$$ and $$f(x)$$ ?

Please provide a lucid explanation.Thanks.

Comment: Strictly, $f$ is the name of the function, whereas $f(x)$ is its value at $x$. Of course, people often refer to the function as $f(x)$.

Comment: $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ is an element in the image of $f$ (for instance, a number). People use $f(x)$ as a shortcut or slight abuse of notation; technically, the function should be referred to as $f$, or $x\mapsto f(x)$. (The first notation has the "inconvenient" of not hinting to the number of "arguments" $f$ takes; the second notation being great, unambiguous, and often utterly cumbersome.)

Answer (score 4):

A function is a machine, a machine that assigns to any value of some set $X$ a unique element $f(x)$ beloging to some set $Y$. So the proper notation would be $f:X\rightarrow Y:x\mapsto f(x)$. You read it as follows: "$f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ which assigns to any $x\in X$ a value $f(x)$ in $Y$". When you write $f$ you refer to the function, when you write $f(x)$ you refer to the element $f(x)\in Y$. Sometimes, by abuse of notation, we write $f(x)$ to refer to the function $f$ and stress that $f$ is dependend on one variable $x$.

Comment: As notations go, the full-fledged version I've seen most often (French undergrad) is $f\colon x\in X \mapsto f(x)\in Y$ for the one-liner, and $$\begin{align} f\colon X &\to Y \\ x &\mapsto f(x)\end{align}$$ for the two-line version.

Answer (score 2):

When we use $f$ it just shows a function . But when we use $f(x)$ it means function at point x.
Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x+1$ .
In this example we have function $f$ and at point $x \in \mathbb{N}$ it has value $f(x)=x+1$

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, any symbol can be anything. You should however use symbols properly. Let me explain.

There are situations in which $f(x)$ is *really* a function. Consider, just to give an example, the differential of a function $f$ at a point $x$: it is the map $Df(x) \colon h \mapsto Df(x)h$. Essentially we have a function attached to each point $x$. In this case there is no abuse of notation.

On the contrary, it is an abuse of notation to refer to a function $f$ as $f(x)$. It is an abuse because you are confusing very different objects: a function and a point (or number). Furthermore, this abuse is dangerous because so many students cannot deal with functions defined by a different letter than $x$. I have had students who were unable to differentiate the function defined by $f(t)=\sin t$ because there was no $x$!